# Django: Serving 2 static folders, one in S3 and the other locally

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm currently serving all my static files in S3 and it's been working fine. But recently we bought a JS plugin and it comes with some HTML, when I serve it from the S3 it breaks down as when it collects the HTML it shows it on an Iframe, and it seems to lack the permissions to access the angular attribute of the ContentWindow. I've been trying to play with the CORS permissions but it doens't seem to do the trick so I want to serve that particular folder as a static file in the server but I really don't know how to configure it so the other files are still served from the S3 and this new ones are served locally.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the ELB Software configuration and adding the other folder to the static routes from there. Sorry for the inconvenience to anyone that saw this post.